# Problem with ajax request for delete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a "todo" application that I've added a delete button to.  The application is already set up to post via an ajax request, but the delete button causes a page re-load after it is clicked.  I feel like preventDefault should... well prevent that from happening, but it doesn't.  Any advice would be much appreciated!

> function to list tasks

```
function taskHtml(task) {
        var checkedStatus = task.done ? "checked" : "";
        var liClass = task.done ? "completed" : "";

        var liElement = '<li id="listItem-' + task.id + '" class="' + liClass + '">' +
        '<div class="view"><input class="toggle" type="checkbox"' + " data-id='" +
        task.id + "'" + checkedStatus + ' /><label>' + task.title + 
        '</label><a class="destroy" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/tasks/' + task.id + 
        '"></a></div></li>';

        return liElement;   

    }
```

> delete task function

```
function deleteTask(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var itemId = $(e.target).data("id");

        $.ajax("/tasks/" + itemId, {
            _method: "DELETE",
        }).success(function(data) {
            var liHtml = taskHtml(data);
            var $li = $("#listItem-" + data.id);
            $li.replaceWith('');
        });
    }


    $.get("/tasks").success( function( data ) {
        var htmlString = "";
        $.each(data, function(index, task) {
            htmlString += taskHtml(task);
        });

        var ulTodos = $('.todo-list');
        ulTodos.html(htmlString);

        $('.toggle').change(toggleTask);

        $('.destroy').click(deleteTask);
    });
```

Comment: Change `$.ajax("/tasks/" + itemId, {` to `$.post("/tasks/" + itemId, {` and see if it works. Also check the console if possible.

Comment: @TheAlpha No dice, but I appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `href` from the `<a>` tag. I will recommend to change this to a `<button>` since you are not taking the user to any other page.

I also suspect this will not work:

`var itemId = $(e.target).data("id");`

Try changing it to:

`var itemId = $(this).parent().data("id");`

Comment: Why would `preventDefault()` not stop the `href` from being followed?